# slow php mail() delivery- 30 to 60 minutes instead of 1-2 minutes

Tags: php, email, send

I have a web-site that has a hosting at some popular hosting company. The problem is that delivery of mail using php mail() function to user emails takes much much more than 1-2 minutes. 40 minutes is the average delivery time I would say... I've contacted the customer support of my hosting company about this issue and they said "*No mail server can guarantee a certain time frame for delivery as any mail server can experience a queue if there are multiple requests going through at once. The queuing is usually temporary and should not last long. However please note that if the recipients server is also queuing you may see a wait time over 30 minutes. There is no way to speed this up.* "

The hosing is shared (NOT a dedicated server... I don't know if that's important).
Any, any ideas on how to reduce the delivery time to 1-2 minutes from 30-60 minutes. (change of our hosting provider is a deal, but not the best one)... Is any other ways to solve this question? (if yes, please provide step-by-step explanations if it doesn't take too much time)....

Thank you.

Comment: Since the resources of the server are shared, another user on the box could be tying up resources. Also there could be many other explanations for the slowness, are you sure it's not your fault on the receiving end (IE: Your email provider doesn't like your server)?

Comment: does this only affect php mail() or mail delivery from this server in general? does it affect ALL recipients or just a few (=>greylisting!) . check the "Received"-Headers of a successfully delivered message to see where the delay happens, read them from bottom up, each received header should say something like "Received from <sending server> by <receiving server> <date and time>. check between which two servers your 30 minute delay happens

Comment: alternative is you could use a 3rd party mail class like the code igniter one & select a different smtp/pop protocol or server with minimal code changes....

Comment: Itz all server issue I dnt think so it can be solved by code..On shared server Mail remain in a long queue...Better to change your server to VPS or dedicated server..

Comment: If I had to guess, sounds like someone else on the server is being a spambot. Or the host has deliberately delayed outgoing mail. Because someone else is being a spambot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to guarantee faster delivery time is to send mail using a mail server you control, or one which provides such guarantees. You can't just change your code while still using your host's server and get any better guarantees.

http://www.sendgrid.com